# Join tables in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have three tables like this:

`user`

```
id | name | department_id
```

`user_verify`

```
id | code | user_id | department_id
```

`department`

```
id | name
```

I want to query on table user_verify and join with other tables to get username and department name.

I tried this in my model:

```
class ListUserVerify extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'user_verify';


    public function getUserVerify()
    {
        return $this->select("{$this->table}.code",'user.fullname','department.name')
                    ->join('user', 'user.id', '=', "{$this->table}.user_id")
                    ->join('department', 'department.id', '=', "{$this->table}.department_id")
                    ->get();
    }
}
```

But this function return null, I don't know what's wrong with my query.

Can you show me what's wrong I did?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Why do you have department_id in both user and user_verify ?

Comment: You shouldn't be creating queries in your model. Use a service instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try it.

```
return \DB::table("{$this->table}")->select("{$this->table}.code",'user.fullname','department.name')
                ->join('user', 'user.id', '=', "{$this->table}.user_id")
                ->join('department', 'department.id', '=', "{$this->table}.department_id")
                ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
return DB::table('user_verify')->leftjoin('user','user.id','=','user_verify.user_id')
           ->leftjoin('department','department.id','=','user_verify.department_id')
           ->select('user.name as username','department.name as departmentname')
           ->get();
```